# Python dictionary list as value - combine elements

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations

I have a dictionary with lists as values. I want to combine every element with another, but only for different keys. The combination should be stored in another dictionary. This dictionary should have keys like, `'sim_1'`, `'sim_2'`, and so on. The values will be a list. This list contains several tuples. The first element of the tuple will be the old key and the second element will be the combined element. 
Lets assume the following example:

```py
dict_old = {'a': ['r1'], 
            'b': ['r1', 'r2', 'r3'], 
            'c': ['r1', 'r2', 'r3'], 
            'd': ['r1'], 
            'e': ['r1', 'r2']}

dict_new = {'sim_1': [('a', 'r1'), ('b', 'r1'), ('c', 'r1'), ('d', 'r1'), ('e', 'r1')]
            'sim_2': [('a', 'r1'), ('b', 'r2'), ('c', 'r1'), ('d', 'r1'), ('e', 'r1')], 
            'sim_3':...}
```

For the `'sim_2'` only the `'b'` changed. In total there would be 18 sims.

I appreciate your help!

Best regards,
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `itertools` package's `product` function you can get a list of combinations. That in combination with some dictionary logic will get you to your `dict_new`:

```
import itertools

dict_old = {'a': ['r1'], 
            'b': ['r1', 'r2', 'r3'], 
            'c': ['r1', 'r2', 'r3'], 
            'd': ['r1'], 
            'e': ['r1', 'r2']}

dict_values = dict_old.values()
dict_keys = dict_old.keys()
combinations = itertools.product(*dict_values)

dict_new = {}
for sim_count, combination in enumerate(combinations):
  sim_key = 'sim_'+str(sim_count+1)
  dict_new[sim_key] = []
  for i, key in enumerate(dict_keys):
    tuple = (key,combination[i])
    dict_new[sim_key].append(tuple)
```